# Vuepress is creating a static site that requires far too many requests, is there a method to reduce this?

Tags: vuepress

[image: VuePress with Webconverger network tab]

I tried setting evergreen to true in [.vuepress/config](https://github.com/Webconverger/wiki/blob/vuepress/.vuepress/config.js) to reduce but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You sure you're not in dev mode?

Comment: I just did a npm run build and deployed that

Comment: Is it by design? There is a service worker option that caches and refreshes with server page changes.